# An application of Riemann-Roch

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a curve, $X$ variety ,everything is projective over field $k$. Morphism $f: C\rightarrow X.$
When deriving the  lower bound for dimension of parameter space of morphisms from curve $C$ to variety $X$, $\dim_{f}Mor(C,X)$, there's an equality
$$\chi(C,f^* T_X)=-K_X.f_* C+(1-g_C)(\dim X).$$

It was claimed a consequence of Riemann-Roch, but I can't see the point. I don't think $f^* T_X$ is of rank 1, hence the R-R for curve doesn't work. I'm not familiar with the explicit form of general R-R.

Comment: Do you know RR for vector bundles? Fairly straightforward generalization of the rank one case.

Comment: @Mohan Haven't met it before, could you offer some ref?

Comment: Any vector bundle on a curve can be filtered by line bundles and both $\chi$ and degree are additive.